# How to update string value by string comparison condition PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want update all values in my tables, but this can kill my database

```
UPDATE Table_1
SET Value  =  'Some string with but changed' 
where value = 'Some string without changes';
```

Can I do this by procedures, and it guarantee that it will not perform in infinty please i need some tips?

Edit

I read about cursors, but how can i use it

Comment: Please expand on why you think an `UPDATE` query can "kill" your database. What do you mean by "kill" and why would you think it can "perform infinitely"?

Comment: I have almost 2 milions rows , and 500 with value = 'Some string without changes';

Comment: And... why would `UPDATE` kill your database? It seems to be the perfect solution to your problem and will not "kill" the database nor run infinitely.

Comment: Ok, thank you is just my conclusion after counting all rows with specific value , it took about a hour. Do you think if cursors can speed up it ?

Comment: Try it and see - however, cursors are typically slower than pure SQL (when they are doing the same thing) as cursors are going to be repeatedly context switching between a PL/SQL context and a SQL context which just adds overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach if your DB is higher than 11g R1 version. Oracle has provided a beautiful package called [DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_parallel_ex.htm#ARPLS67330) which is used for large DMLS or any process which can be split into chunks and can be parallely done.

Comment: I don't think DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE is best suited in this case where only 500 rows (with value = 'Some string without changes' out of 2 mn) expected to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL seems fine and that is the preferred solution. A cursor will normally be far, far slower.

If you cannot create an index and the update above is really that slow, try the following. Considering I don't have the rest of the table definition to work with, I assume your primary key is a single field named ID:

First, create a temporary table with only the matching records:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp as
  SELECT * 
  FROM Table_1
  WHERE value = 'Some string without changes';
```

Then, update using this temporary table:

```
UPDATE Table_1 SET 
  Table_1.Value = 'Some string with but changed'
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM Temp 
  WHERE Temp.ID = Table_1.ID
);
```